# Rewrite a secondary domain to a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I bought two domains:
www.juridischehulponline.nl
www.onlinejuridischehulp.nl

And I'd like them to link to the subfolder of my hosting: www.zuidveste.eu/juridisch and the new domain has to be displayed as the new domain. So if I surf to www.juridischehulponline.nl I'd like to see: www.juridischehulponline.nl and not www.zuidveste.eu/juridisch.

However, if I rewrite and redirect the subfolder to the new domain, I get a: "too many redirects" error. Since it'll go to www.juridischehulponline.nl where an .htaccess is found which will redirect to www.juridsichehulponline.nl

and if I proxy the domain, my new domain keeps being displayed, however simple blogging systems, such as cutenews, won't work, because they see the absolute path as www.zuidveste.eu/juridisch. But due to the .htaccess, that part will be rewritten and the path of www.juridischehulponline.nl/index.php is given; which doesn't exist.

I've deleted the .htaccess in the /juridisch folder, but I don't know how this can be solved.

Can anyone help me?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use proxy, but improve the .htaccess-structure: place only a .htaccess in your zuidveste.eu root:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine ON
Options +FollowSymLinks

#redirect non-www to www-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^juridischehulponline.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.juridischehulponline.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect non-www to www-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^onlinejuridischehulp.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onlinejuridischehulp.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect non-www to www-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zuidveste.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zuidveste.eu/$1 [R=301,L]

#rewrite other domains to the subfolder, keeping the attributes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.juridischehulponline.nl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.onlinejuridischehulp.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/juridisch/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /juridisch/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This code redirects the 3 non-www domains to their www-alternative, so the visitors will see that they are redirected. On the other hand, if they visit the 2 `.nl`-domains, the urls will be rewritten and the users will not see this change in their address-bar.

Nevertheless, take care for duplicate content in search engines. I recommend using a canonical-meta-tag, as explained here: http://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've implemented it, however if I go to:

juridischehulponline.nl/cute

I'm still getting redirected, any idea?

Comment: are you going to www.juridischehulponline.nl/cute, or without www.? I redirected every non-www to www-domain. If this is not what you want, you can change this. So, what is not working is that you go to http://www.juridischehulponline.nl/cute, and you want this to rewrite to http://www.zuidveste.eu/juridisch/cute ? Does this last url exist when you type in that one?

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible, but when I go to (www.)juridischehulponline.nl/cute, I'd like to see: www.juridischehulponline.nl/cute displayed in the addressbar.

However, now I see www.zuidveste.eu/juridisch/cute

Comment: sure, this is possible ! This is exactly what this code should do ! As I can see, there is still a 301-redirect somewhere. Can you comment the non-www to www-lines in the .htaccess (although this should not be the problem) and make sure there is no other .htaccess (also not in the cute-directory)?

Comment: Thank again for the reply, I tried to change the non-www to www. but it didn't make a difference. I think the problem is laying in the .htaccess

Www.zuidveste.eu/htaccess.txt

This is my .htaccess (of course in txt-form, because I couldn't attach it otherwise)

Comment: Unfurtonately not, I included my current .htaccess file, because there is a second 301, however it is needed for the mainsite I think.

Www.zuidveste.eu/htaccess.txt

Comment: I updated the code with the rewriterule which was already present in your .htaccess-file. From your current .htaccess-file, you can remove the 2 lines having `zuidveste` in it, and replace them with the corresponding lines from my code. The last part is ok and must be kept for proper working (starting the line ending on /images). Please mark this question as solved if this solved your problem.